# onclick is not working in the table row [javascript]

Tags: javascript, json, onclick

I am new in javascript
in this code i am printing json data into table but not whole data only a `bookName`.
so my problem is that while i'm try to click on the book's name for instance, The Night Fire, Murder, The Death Higgler etc.. it's not working

so here i dont know this is the right way or wrong to write `onclick` because i'm new in javascript and may be that's why its not working while i'm click on the data of that column
but i want it's clickable

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```js
let bookDetails = [
    {
        bookId: "1",
        bookName: "The Night Fire",
        bookDescription: "description the night fire",
        bookAuthor: "Arnold Bennett ",
        bookPages: "10",
        category: "horror",
        price: "120",
        year: "2001"
    },
    {
        bookId: "2",
        bookName: "Murder",
        bookDescription: "description Murder",
        bookAuthor: "Arnold Bennett ",
        bookPages: "110",
        category: "Mystery",
        price: "130",
        year: "2019"
    },
    {
        bookId: "3",
        bookName: "The Death Higgler",
        bookDescription: "description the Higgler",
        bookAuthor: "Coppard",
        bookPages: "80",
        category: "horror",
        price: "140",
        year: "2020"
    },
    {
        bookId: "4",
        bookName: "The Open Boat",
        bookDescription: "description The Open Boat",
        bookAuthor: "Stephen",
        bookPages: "30",
        category: "Fantasy",
        price: "200",
        year: "2018"
    }]


function toShowTable(bookDetails) {
    messageTable(" ");
    let table = "<table border = 1 cellpadding = 10 ><th colspan=3 >Book Names</th>"
    for (key in bookDetails) {
        table += "<tr><td>" + bookDetails[key].bookName + "</td>";
        bookDetails[key].bookName.onclick = function () {
            console.log("hii");
        }
    } messageTable(table);
}
function messageTable(variable) {
    document.getElementById("messageTable").innerHTML = variable;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Book Store information C</title>
    <script src="add.js"></script>
    <style>
        th,
        td,
        p,
        input {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="showTable" onclick="toShowTable(bookDetails)">
<p id="messageTable"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bookDetails[key].bookName is not a HTML element, so you cannot have onclick event on this as you have written. What you can do is write onclick function seperately and pass it in `td` like this: `table += '<tr><td onclick="functionToCall()"'> .......`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this? You won't need the messageTable function

```
function toShowTable(bookDetails) {
  const messageTable=document.getElementById("messageTable");
  messageTable.innerHTML = '';
    let table=document.createElement("table");
    bookDetails.forEach((item)=>{
      let row= table.insertRow(-1);
        let cell=row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML=item.bookName;
        cell.addEventListener('click',()=>{
          alert(item.bookName);
        })
    })
    messageTable.appendChild(table);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like

```
function toShowTable(bookDetails) {
    messageTable(" ");
    let table = "<table border = 1 cellpadding = 10 ><th colspan=3 >Book Names</th>"
    for (key in bookDetails) {
        table += "<tr onclick='yourFunction(somevalue)'><td>" + bookDetails[key].bookName + "</td>";
    }
    messageTable(table);
}

function yourFunction(value) {
    // do someting
}
```